# i have installed CodeIgniter but some error displayed in installation process that's why i am ask for you

Tags: php

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: 8192

Message: Creation of dynamic property CI_URI::$config is deprecated

Filename: core/URI.php

Line Number: 102

Backtrace:

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\ci3\index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once

i have install but some error

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Can you please elaborate that how do you installed the CodeIgniter, like by manually or using composer?